# Display my forms in another class

Tags: c#

I recently developped an application for a student project, and everything works fine. However, if I'm asking something here, you can certainly assume that the whole thing isn't so functional...and you'd be right hohoho. Let's get started. Basically the functional version of my project uses an UI console.

It runs, but from an user point of view, working with something like this isn't the most amazing stuff in the world. So I decided to replace my old console by some Windows Forms.

[Project global render with console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrDWW.png)

[Project global render with form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rtLp.png)

This is where things become wrong. I have "3" classes :

- **Program.cs** (the main program with all the serious stuff)
- **formOne.cs** (the first form with a button for each options)
- **form/Two to Five/.cs** (each options open the corresponding form)

At some point, **Program.cs** will launch **formOne.cs**, and from there the user should be able to navigate between the various options and so the various forms...but nope. **formOne.cs** opens, and then we can't click on anything (well we can but nothing happens). I did a mistake somewhere, I would like to know where and how to fix it. Here's how I proceeded :

(this is the basic algorithm, not the whole code)

**Program.cs :**

```
class Program {

formOne winRecep = new formOne();
formTwo winCrea = new formTwo();
formThree winSearch = new formThree();
formFour winDel = new formFour();
formFive winView = new formFive();

winRecep.ShowDialog();
string userChoice = winRecep.getUserChoice();

switch(userChoice){

case "create new task" :
    winCrea.ShowDialog();
    break;

case "search a task" :
    winSearch.ShowDialog();
    break;

case "delete a task" :
    winDel.ShowDialog();
    break;

case "view my tasks" :
    winView.ShowDialog();
    break;

}

}
```

**formOne.cs :**

```
class formOne {

        string userChoice;

        public formOne()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string getUserChoice()
        {
            return userChoice;
        }

        private void formOne_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //blabla update current date, current hour...
        }

        private void buttonOptionOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            userChoice = "create new task";
        }

        private void buttonOptionTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            userChoice = "search a task";
        }

        private void buttonOptionThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            userChoice = "delete a task";
        }

        private void buttonOptionFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            userChoice = "view my tasks";
        }

}
```

It seems pretty clear to me, but I did a mistake somewhere. I would like to work in Program.cs instead of formOne.cs because, well, everything is in Program.cs so the most logical way to proceed is certainly to work here instead of bring informations and variables everywhere accross the classes.

Could someone help me and explain why it's wrong ?

EDIT : Program.cs using Application doesn't solve the thing :

```
class Program {

        var winRecep = new formOne();
        var createtask = new formTwo();
        var viewTask = new formThree();
        var searchTask = new formFour();
        var deleteTask = new formFive();

Application.Run(winRecep);
string userChoice = winRecep.getUserChoice();

switch(userChoice){

case "create new task" :
    Application.Run(createtask);
    break;

case "search a task" :
    Application.Run(searchTask);
    break;

case "delete a task" :
    Application.Run(deleteTask);
    break;

case "view my tasks" :
    Application.Run(viewTask);
    break;

}

}
```

Comment: You need to create instance for selected form as you did for `formOne`. `var winTwo = new formTwo(); winTwo.ShowDialog()`

Comment: The problem is this: Application.Run(winRecep). Either keep that one and remove the switch statement OR keep the switch statement and create a case for winRecep invocation. Why? Because you are creating more than one thread loop for you applicaton and you only need 1.

Answer (score -1):

You need to start your main form like this:

```
var mainForm = new formOne();
Application.Run(mainForm);
```

This starts the [windows message loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902(v=vs.110).aspx).  Without a message loop, your application can't respond to any events (such as mouse clicks or keypresses).

Comment: Ok, it's maybe a better syntax but it doesn't solve the problem. I edited my post to show you how I used Application, if something's wrong...

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you should do, is opening the main form using `Application.Run`, as already suggested. This starts the message loop which is essential for the rest of the execution:

```
var mainForm = new formOne();
Application.Run(mainForm);
```

Then use that form to open all others. Closing the form started with `Application.Run` will close the application since the message loop will end too. So on any action, like a button click or a command written, open the form you need. You can call `Show` to open the other form and make it possible to still access the main form, or `ShowDialog` which will block further actions until the child form was closed.